# Regular expression for numeric with dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need an Regular Expression to match exactly as below

XXXX.XXX.XXX

X - is only numeric

Example:-
0876.513.972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go good sir:

^ is front anchor, \d is numeric, {X} is number of occurrences, \. is dot escape since it's a wild char in regex, and $ is back anchor.

```
/^\d{4}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}
```

This captures 4 numbers, a decimal, 3 numbers, decimal, 3 numbers.

You can see it diagrammed at http://www.regexper.com/#%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D

Comment: You need front and back anchors, and should probably use \d

Comment: Thanks especially for the link

Comment: @Enjoys Turtles Yeah, I didn't see your answer until after I posted mine. I didn't know about the `\d`, but I'm going to start using it now!

Comment: No worries :) practice for fun: http://regex.alf.nu/

Comment: Oh, way cool. Thanks for the tip.